# Faster way to copy external tables or their fields in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I didn't know that my external tables had expiry dates and lost half of them. Is there a way to copy the external tables and just change the data source on each one? Or even if I can just copy the fields then that would help so much.

Any assistance would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: More details needed - what are "your external tables"?

Comment: The sources of the external tables are Google Sheets

Comment: Are your external tables missing? What exactly do you want to copy?

Comment: Hi, no half of them expired (I managed to save the other half). They are all identical though except for the table name and the Google sheet URI, so I wanted to know if there's a way to copy the ones that didn't expire or if I could just copy the field names in one go without having to create those fields again one by one (I have to create them manually)

Comment: @PieterleRoux You want to create another external table by copying the existing ones?

Comment: It seems like I found a much faster way. I'm adding the fields by choosing Edit with Text and then I used the online JSON template which I completed and copied onto a notepad. This will save me weeks of work as I don't have to add one field at a time. Thanks again though :)